# MikroTik beep on RDP

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

I am a newbie in MikroTik RouterOS.

How can I add a rule or script to **beep** when some one tries to connect to a special port on one of interfaces?

For example I need to know if someone is trying to ftp to my server from outside world.

Comment: "I need to know if someone is trying to ftp to my server from outside world" <-- If it's connected to the Internet, then someone is attacking it. I guarantee it.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that directly.

Workaround could be using firewall rule to add source ip to addresslist:

```
/ip firewall filter add action=add-src-to-address-list address-list=beeplist
    address-list-timeout=1m1s chain=input disabled=no dst-port=21 protocol=tcp
```

and then run script to check'n'beep:

```
:if ([ :len [ip firewall address-list find where list=beeplist]]>0) do={:beep}
```

periodically via scheduler:

```
/system scheduler add interval=60s name=beeplist on-event=":if ([ :len [ip firewall address-list find where list=beeplist]]>0) do={:beep}"
```

Entries in address-list are going to be deleted via `address-list-timeout` settings.

Still, you are going to hear a lot of beeps...

Comment: +1. Noone likely considers this a good feature to impolkement because mosst routers wont have anyone hearing them scream, being in cabinets, server rooms or - in the case of mikrotik - up on towers :)

Comment: Also, the last time I looked at firewall logs I get attacked a few times a minute. I might as well just set it to beep every few seconds, would but just as accurate.